# How to get static files from .nuget package to my local /bin folder of consuming project

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

So I do have following set up:

A project which is turned into a .nuget package. Let's call it provider.csproj turned into provider.nuget. Also, there are some `.json` files that need to live with .dll in the /lib folder of the package. I achieved this by copying those .json files into the package /lib folder by explicit instructions in the provider.nuspec files which look like following:

```
<files>
      <file src="required.json" target="lib/netstandard2.0">
</files>
```

Now that code ensure that when  Provider.nuget package is generated, there is in fact a required.json file copied with the output .dll and everything works fine.

I can actually reference this nuget package in another project, which for now lets call it `consumer.csproj`

That works great too. So basically if I have to run consumer.csproj as it is then, there are no issues. It goes to .nuget/packages folder and finds my package there and executes all fine.

Problem occurs when I try to publish consumer.csproj. When I run `dotnet publish` on the project it copies provider.dll and it does not copy required.json with it.

How can I tell Consumer project to copy required.json file locally in its /bin folder when I reference provider.nuget package?

Comment: Hey Lost, did you manage to solve this?